# Enable Keep-alive code doesn't affect with our website

Tags: wordpress, performance, optimization

We have our website which is built on Wordpress CMS.
This website speed is very low (about 42% as per the gtmetrix result).

Website URL: https://www.ttademo.timesandtrendsacademy.com/

So, I have done some speed optimization related activities to improve our website speed. So for that, I have used two optimization plugin for the same.

1) wp-fastest-cache 2) wp-optimize

After doing optimization through those plugin, our website improve with 4% only.
And as per gtmetrix tool report, I have added below code to Enable-Keep-Alive, but it doesn't affect with our website.

```
# TN START ENABLE KEEP ALIVE
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
# TN END ENABLE KEEP ALIVE
```

Could you please let me know what we need to implement to improve our website speed.

Thanks,
Gopal

Answer (score 0):

**To improve your website, follow the points**

```
1. install W3 total cache plugin and wp-smushit plugin and customized it.
2. Enable gzip compression
3. delete old post revisions
4. Identify un-used images, CSS and JS files and remove.
5. Image optimization. 
6. JS & CSS minify and optimize.
7. Removed un-used plugins
8. Leverage browser caching(add code in .htaccess)
9. use lazy loading
```

Comment: 1) Using fastest cache and also used smushit  2) Already added gzip compression code (doesn't affect) 3) Post revisions removed through the wp-optimize plugin 4) How to identify unused js/css 5) Image optimization done 6) How to minify js & css 7) Removed unused plugins 8) Added code for Leverage browsing cache (doesn't affect) 9) How to use lazy loading